# Sum of two table values per time and find minimum of sum result in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, report

I have two database.
in database one I have a table (507.000 record for one day data)

```
-- insert data from database_1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AccountBalance;
CREATE TABLE #AccountBalance
( AccountNumber VARCHAR(20),AccountBalance MONEY,TranTime DATETIME);
```

Sample data is AccountBalance:

```
BankAccountNumber   AccountBalance  transactiontime
01003930510         42006.00        2021-03-20
45033323462         4682.00         2021-03-20
23035469562         3388.00         2021-03-20
23005168662         617.00          2021-03-20
01004829050         44640.00        2021-03-20
```

Sample data for TransactionCards

```
BankAccountNumber   Balance     TransactionTime
45033323462         245428.00   2021-03-21 00:06:47.000
23038201062         140983.00   2021-03-21 00:06:49.000
45019249962         60416.00    2021-03-21 00:07:46.000
45004876662         588154.00   2021-03-21 00:10:46.000
45004876662         627867.00   2021-03-22 00:17:44.000
```

in database two I have a table with 18 millions records

**Aim** : find one value and call that `Minimum Value Of Sum(balance) per record`

**I trreid**:
0. Insert data in one database with temporary table and linked-Server.

1. Write cursor like below (fetch BankAccountNumber from CardTransaction and if not exists same BankAccountNumber Insert into #Account balance ,If exists update balance  )
2. calculate sum of all SUM(AccountBalance) per fetch(record or per time) and insert result into #Result (business is clear in cursor)
3. Select Min(AccountBalance ) From #Result

```
-- Create tables for calculate
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AccountBalance;
CREATE TABLE #AccountBalance
( BankAccountNumber VARCHAR(20),AccountBalance MONEY,TranTime DATETIME); -- I inserted 507.000 row  record data in this table

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Result 
CREATE TABLE #Result (SumOfBalance MONEY, BankAccountNumber VARCHAR(20), TranTime DATETIME)

-- variable for cursor procces
DECLARE @BankAccountNumber VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @TransactionBalance MONEY;
DECLARE @TranTime DATETIME;

DECLARE @OldBankAccountNumber VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @OldAccountBalance MONEY;
DECLARE @OldTranTime DATETIME = '2021-03-20';

-- start cursor
DECLARE CR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT rt.BankAccountNumber,rt.Balance,rt.TransactionTime
    FROM RawData.dbo.CardTransaction rt;

PRINT '-------Sum of all AccountBalance Report per time------';

OPEN CR;
FETCH NEXT FROM CR
INTO @BankAccountNumber,
     @TransactionBalance,
     @TranTime;

-- insert sum of account balanace into result table
INSERT INTO #Result (SumOfBalance,BankAccountNumber,TranTime)
SELECT SUM(AccountBalance),@BankAccountNumber,@TranTime FROM #AccountBalance 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND dbo.DoContinue() = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT BankAccountNumber = @OldBankAccountNumber , AccountBalance = @OldAccountBalance FROM dbo.AccountBalance WHERE BankAccountNumber = @BankAccountNumber
    IF @OldBankAccountNumber=@BankAccountNumber -- if exists record in account balance
    BEGIN
        -- update account balance with new balance
        UPDATE #AccountBalance
        SET AccountBalance = @TransactionBalance
        WHERE BankAccountNumber = @BankAccountNumber

        -- insert new sum of account balanace into result table
        INSERT INTO #Result (SumOfBalance,BankAccountNumber,TranTime)
        SELECT SUM(AccountBalance),@BankAccountNumber,@TranTime FROM #AccountBalance 
    END;

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- 
        INSERT INTO #AccountBalance (BankAccountNumber,AccountBalance,TranTime)
        VALUES (@BankAccountNumber, @TransactionBalance, @TranTime);

        -- insert new sum of account balanace into result table
        INSERT INTO #Result (SumOfBalance,BankAccountNumber,TranTime)
        SELECT SUM(AccountBalance),@BankAccountNumber,@TranTime FROM #AccountBalance  
    END;

    PRINT @BankAccountNumber

    FETCH NEXT FROM CR
    INTO @BankAccountNumber,@TransactionBalance,@TranTime;
END;

CLOSE CR;
DEALLOCATE CR;
```

**Problem** : Very slowly work and I can't wait one day for run cursor . and I cant see result, but I guess not reliable value(I checked 2000 record)

**What I need** : I need fast and reliable solution

**Expected table like below** :

```
SumOfAccountBalance             transactiontime
98,721                          2021-03-21 10:01:00
339,464                         2021-04-22 01:01:00
480,447                         2021-04-23 01:01:00
540,863                         2021-04-23 02:01:00
1,129,017                       2021-04-23 03:01:00
1,168,730                       2021-04-23 15:01:00
```

**Final Expected** :

```
MinCriticalPointAccountBalance  transactiontime
98,721                          2021-03-21 10:01:00
```

Comment: " find one value and call that Minimum Value Of Sum(balance) per record" . . . What does this mean?  Sample data and desired results would really help.  I really doubt a cursor is needed for this.

Comment: *"find one value and call that Minimum Value Of Sum(balance) per record"* If we take this *literally* then `SELECT TOP (1) {Any column in your table} AS [Minimum Value Of Sum(balance) per record] FROM dbo.YourTable;` , which'll give you single arbitrary value, and call (alias) it "Minimum Value Of Sum(balance) per record". I doubt that is what you want though, so you need to elaborate a lot more.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This definition is a bit confusing and mean : Total sum for each change or addition from `CardTransaction`. And finally, find the minimum amount of balances.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok ,I need more time for add Sample data in question.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, this is not what I want.It's a little hard for me to explain.But the written cursor could be a better explanation.But if you ask me what you want, I say I want a list of total balances with history so that I can find the lowest amount on what day and how much it was. But I have a condition, every time the account balance is repeated, the total sum also changes. And the balance is updated, This update is done by date. I want to have a criterion for the minimum balance of accounts. critical point for which time it has reached its minimum point.
I'm sorry, because my English is weak.

Comment: Seems like we really need that sample data and expected results @Amirhossein .

Comment: @GordonLinoff this sample data is enough ?

Comment: what's the expected output for your sample data?

Comment: @larnu: add sample and expected like sample

Comment: @Amirhossein your expected output must match the sample data provided otherwise it gets confusing